# how to create a module in dotnetnuke connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, module, dotnetnuke

I have a Dotnetnuke portal I want to add a module to it. This module have to connect to a mysql database. How do I Create a DNN module in visual studio that can connect to a MYSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any DotNetNuke specifics, but there is a .NET connector for MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/